# KendoUI + WebView - input type= text/tel/number - bugged

Tags: mobile, input, keyboard, cordova, kendo-ui

I'm working on mobile application, using Kendo UI framework.

Currently, I have a major problem with Text/Numeric inputs, on android tablet devices.

To describe the nature of my problem I will use an example:

I have a 3 simple inputs:

```
 <label>Phone </label>
 <input type="tel" id="some_id"  />

 <label>Text </label>
 <input type="text" id="some_id1"  />

 <label>Number </label>
 <input type="number" id="some_id2"  />
```

Problems that I encountered are:

1. It is impossible to input text using Android Keyboard on Asus
   Transformer Pad if word is not in dictionary. (you can write "Mother"
   and submit, but you cant write "asgdssvdsfa" and submit (wont give
   any effect).  This problem does not exists when I test my app on
   Samsung Galaxy Tab. Other thing is that on Asus you have to submit every word before it appear inside text field.
2. This problem exists on both ASUS and Samsung devices: When input
       type is set to tel or number, its impossible to write anything.
       Numeric keyboard appears, you press the buttons , and nothing
       appears inside a text field.

To check that out, I turned off every Kendo .js and .css files, and problem still exists, I have no idea what can possibly cause it.

Comment: Keyboard input is very flakey in PhoneGap / Cordova on Android. It varies by keyboard. For example on my Android JellyBean device the stock Android keyboard works fine, Swype will only enter the 1st letter of any word, and SwiftKey the backspace key doesn't work. I'm not sure if it is an android or a phonegap issue, but I suspect one or the other.

Comment: Well.. problem was in cordova version. After updating to 2.9.0, every input works good. Problem seems to be solved.